# How to use @Query in Retrofit? Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm currently trying to make an ApiInterface. I'm trying to manipulate API URL by using query. So far the URL I'm using is

[https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key={apiKey}&language=en-US&query={query}](https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=%7BapiKey%7D&language=en-US&query=%7Bquery%7D)

The url above I'm trying to change the "query" So I created this interface:

```
@GET("3/search/movie?api_key=${BuildConfig.MOVIE_TOKEN}&language=en-US&")
fun getMovies(
        @Query("query") query: String
): Call<SearchMovieResponse>
```

And it works well, but what if the case of the URL is this:

[https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{id}?api_key=7fad718afb38c7fe3fbe9da94e0d54e6](https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/%7Bid%7D?api_key=7fad718afb38c7fe3fbe9da94e0d54e6)

Where I'm trying to manipulate the {id}. Is the interface like this?

```
@GET("3/movie/{id}?api_key=${BuildConfig.MOVIE_TOKEN}")
fun getMovieById(
    @Query("id") id: String
):Call<SearchDetailMovieResponse>
```

Please help me understand how to utilize the annotations to modify the API urls

Answer (score 2):

To use the `@Query` properly in the case of the following URL:

[https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{id}?api_key=7fad718afb38c7fe3fbe9da94e0d54e6](https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/%7Bid%7D?api_key=7fad718afb38c7fe3fbe9da94e0d54e6)

You would need to write your interface as such

```
@GET("3/movie/{id}")
fun getMovieById(
    @Path("id") id: String,
    @Query("api_key") apiKey: String = BuildConfig.MOVIE_TOKEN
):Call<SearchDetailMovieResponse>
```

For more information refer to the [documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Query.html).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying a lot of things on this. NGL, the docs appears hard to make sense of.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Path annotation for this.

```
@GET("3/movie/{id}?api_key=${BuildConfig.MOVIE_TOKEN}")
fun getMovieById(
    @Path("id") id: String
):Call<SearchDetailMovieResponse>
```

**Additional Info:**

If you have parameter in middle of url and want to give dynamic value then use @Path annotation as you have id in middle of url.

e-g https://test-api/3/profile. 3 is param in middle of url in that case we use @Path

If you don't have parameter in middle of url and want to pass parameters at end of url with key value pair then better to use @Query

e-g https://test-api/profile?user_id=3 user_id is key value parameter in that case we use @Query.

Note: I am sharing as far as I understood.